# How to get the current user's (who is logged in) user_id in social engine?

Tags: php, socialengine

php in my socialengine directory. How should I get user's user_id who is logged in? can you give me an exact example?

Comment: Hi, Kim. Welcome to Stack Overflow. You'll get better answers if you tell people what you've already tried, and why it's not working. What reference material have you already looked at?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're doing this within a controller which extends either Core_Controller_Action_Standard or Engine_Content_Widget_Abstract you can use the following;

```
Engine_Api::_()->user()->getViewer()->getIdentity();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$viewer = Engine_Api::_()->user()->getViewer()->getIdentity();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of `User_Model_User`, let's say `user` and call it's method, e.g. `$user.getIdentity()`

As simple as your question.